# How to open Glade Interface Designer on Windows 10?

Tags: c, user-interface, windows-10, glade, msys2

I'm trying to install and run Glade on Windows 10 to build a GTK GUI with C. However after downloading glade from their homepage and running pacman comands in MSYS, i cant find a way to actually launch glade, not "glade", not "install glade", nothing. Does anyone uses Glade on Win10 and knows how to set it up properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you already installed it? if you haven't, then install glade properly by running the command on msys2 terminal:

```
pacman -Syu mingw-w64-x86_64-glade
```

pacman will automatically install Glade with GTK3 and all other dependencies for you.

Now to launch it by typing:

```
C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\glade.exe
```

Or you can add the `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin\` directory to your `PATH` environment variable to launch Glade or any msys2 app any time just by typing its name on cmd or any other terminal.  (If you don't know how to do that then ask).

e.g: all packages installed on `msys2` can be found on `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin`

Comment: bruh, i already gave up on glade and went to use visual studio 2017. but i tried your answer and it seemed so similar to everything i tried but this actually worked, many thanks!

Comment: You're most welcome. I really know about msys(2) and I like it. I've been a frequent contributor to it.